# Order of Highlighted Content showing

Tags: web-part

I want the most recently added page to be shown in my highlighted content web part (carousel). For this I have put in the filter "Title includes the words: Videos" to chose the right pages and below it I have selected "Sort by: Most Recent." However, the order is the wrong way round. I.e. the first page published is the first featured one and one has to cycle through to get to the latest. How do I change it so the latest page with the word "Video" in the title is always shown?

Thanks!